# trying to output a dictionary with occurences of all words of given text

Tags: python, dictionary

words is one string including different words separated by a space.
here is my code:

```
def dictionary(words):
    d={};
    for i in words:
        begin = 0;
        while (words[i:i+1] != " "):
            if (words[begin:i] in d):
                d[words[begin:i]] += 1;
            else:
                d[words[begin:i]] = 1;
        begin = i + 1;
    return d;
```

and unfortunately i got the error message below:

```
File "C:/Python27/projectfiles/dictionary.py", line 5, in dictionary
    while (words[i:i+1] != " "):
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

any help? or ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do with that slice? `i` is the word, trying to add 1 to it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You should be using `for i in range(len(words)):`, not `for i in words:`

Comment: Ah okay nice seems to be evident, true, but now i cant check this, because  the shell dont react. it doesnt execute the function and i only can make newlines by typing enter. no messages. Somebody know what it means? sorry i am a beginner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is words a `str` object? Then try the following:

```
from collections import Counter

def dictionary(words):
    return Counter(words.split())
```

The `collections.Counter` type already counts the times an item is inside a `list`. The `split` method turns a `str` into a list of `str` divided by the `str` given as argument, and it defaults to spaces. You should probably need to handle commas and dots yourself but they weren't being handle in your example either.

Example:

```
dictionary("Be water my friend, be water and be fluid.")
```

Outputs:

```
Counter({'water': 2, 'be': 2, 'Be': 1, 'and': 1, 'my': 1, 'fluid.': 1, 'friend': 1})
```

It works as a normal `dict`. The order may be different in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without input, I can't guess what's wrong with your current function.  But I can, however, provide a way to perform the same function.

### How you may want to write it

You should remove punctuation and casing when counting words (to accommodation for beginning and ending of sentences). Additionally, collection's counter is an already written brilliant class to use.  You can even cast it to dictionary and then **boom** you have a dictionary with the desired items.

```
from collections import Counter
import re
words = "I like to walk on the beach and enjoy life.  Beach walks are fun."

def dictionary(words):
    return Counter(re.sub("([^a-z ])", "", words.lower()).split())
print( dictionary(words) )
```

Comment: Casting `Counter` to `dict` is unnecesary as it already works as a `dict`. You are assuming capital letter are not needed (which may or may not be true) and you are also removing other characters such as digits, "-" and so on.